# Why do i get the location of the element of an array instead of its value ? C

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char c[] = "Hello";
    char h = c[4];
    printf("%s",h);
```

}
Why does h result in the position of the element,not the value ?The error is : warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: You are getting the value, but are trying to print it as a string, not a character, use `%c`

Comment: Just about any book or tutorial or lecture about C should have taught you that the `"%s"` format is to print *null-terminated strings* and the format for printing single characters is `"%c"`.

Comment: Sorry, but which part of the warning was not clear?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Understanding pointers and format strings is not easy, every beginner has problems with that. Not every book explains them in a way that works for every person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

`printf("%s",h);`

causes warning as you mentioned

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

because `h` is declared as `char` type and to print character variable format specifier is `%c`.  So use `%c` instead of `%s` as `%s` expects argument of `char*` type not `char` type.

*Why does h result in the position of the element,not the value ?* No if you print like `printf("%c\n",h);` it prints the value what `c[4]` holds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Do you know if char and char * can be compared  ?

Comment: Didn't get exactly what you are asking ?.  Both `char` and `char*` are different. For e.g `char ch='h';` and `char *ptr="hello";` then you can compare `ch` and `*ptr` like `if(ch==*ptr) {  }` but you can't compare like `if(ch==ptr) {  }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the location, you are getting a random number retrieved from your memory.

`char h` is a single character.

`char[]` or `char*` is the address (memory location) of the start of a sequence of chars, one after the other.

`%s` expects you to give it a `char*`.

You are giving it `h`, a single `char`.

So what the computer does (for historical reasons) is that it lets you get away with this even though it is wrong (this warning should really be an error). Getting away with it means it takes the ASCII value of the character stored in h (and depending on whether you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit system, a few random bytes following that character in memory), so a random number, and interprets it as the memory address of a range of characters (a `char*`), and tries to print that.

By all means this should crash, but you are "getting lucky" in that the number you happen to end up with seems to be a valid memory address in your program, so you're printing a few random characters.

What you should be doing is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char c[] = "Hello";
    char h = c[4];
    printf("%c",h); // Change %s to %c, which is for char, not char*
}
```

or alternately:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char c[] = "Hello";
    char h[2] = { 0, 0 }; // Make sure you have an extra "0" at the end that indicates the end of the string.
    h[0] = c[4];
    printf("%s",h);
}
```

If your compiler is new enough, you could probably even write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    char c[] = "Hello";
    char h[2] = { c[4], 0 }; // Make sure you have an extra "0" at the end that indicates the end of the string.
    printf("%s",h);
}
```

for the last variant, but most older compilers can't understand that (again, for historical reasons).